# QPainter with QVulkanWindow

Tags: c++, qt, vulkan

With QOpenGLWidget we can mix in calls to openGL and QPainter by overwriting `void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)`. Is there a possibility of doing the something similar with QVulkanWindow and accessing QPainter functionality?

Environment: Latest Qt as of now (5.11), VS 2017, Windows 10